# Get records added last week, but exclude records added today

Tags: mysql, sql

So I need to collect all the records from the database that where added last week. Currently I'm using the sql query listed below:

```
SELECT * FROM table DATE(date_added) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

However, this because of the greater than sign, it also takes the records added today. How can I select only the records added last week and exclude the records being added from today on?

Comment: There's this keyword `AND`

Comment: it's much better to calculate period before quering, and then just use `BETWEEN` for two specific dates

Comment: @Uriil The DATE() function on the date_added column is inefficient, but I suspect the other bit is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table where 
DATE(date_added) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
AND 
DATE(date_added) < CURDATE()
```